# Mysql "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have got problem with my mysql. It started with that I was importing a dump with the workbench tool. I waited about 30 mins for it to finish but nothing happened so i decided to press stop, to my surprise that did no work either so i close the application and opened it again. Under the tab server status i could see that it was still working on it i decided then to wait a while longer to see what would happen. The sql script seemed to finish but after that mysql was unusable. I can no longer start mysql if i do it with the workbench tool i get the error

> Start server
>
> A permission error occurred while attempting to start the
>   server. Administrator password was possibly wrong.

If i try to access mysql by CL

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
```

I get errors like this.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

How can i fix this so i can use my mysql databases again?

Comment: Maybe if you delete the /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock, restart your mysqld service and finally try to access to mysql client.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is:

- Delete mysqld.sock
  `rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- Restart the mysqld service
  `service mysqld stop`
  `service mysqld start`
- Try to access to mysql client
  `mysql -u root -h localhost -p`

Note:

```
If you really need connect to that port, then do it, avoid that otherwise.
```